# How can I make ASCII art <pre> tag responsive without media queries?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have my username as an ASCII art banner/header, and I'd like to make it more responsive. Right now I'm using media queries, but I'm wondering if there's a way to make it scale with/inside a CSS grid container, so I don't need to use media queries, as I think that would result in the code being less "bloated" and easier to maintain.

###### Here's what I've tried so far:

- `width` with `min()`, `max()`, `clamp()` and `calc()` functions containing various **vw** and **vh** values.
- `width` with just a **vw** value, since I saw it being suggested elsewhere.
- `font-size` with `min()`, `max()`, `clamp()` and `calc()` functions containing percentages.
- `white-space: pre-wrap;`
- `white-space: pre-line;`
- `word-wrap: break-word;`

`white-space: pre-wrap;` and `white-space: pre-line;` *kind of* work, but they completely break the ASCII art.

None of these things have made it scale properly for me, though.

###### And here's my current code:

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 7.25rem auto 5rem;
  grid-template-areas: "header header" "main sidebar" "footer footer";
  min-height: 100vh;
}

header {
  grid-area: header;
}

header pre {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 70%;
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 700px) {
  body {
    grid-template-rows: 6rem auto 5rem;
  }
  header {
    font-size: 55%;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <pre>
 ___       __    ________   ___    _________   ________   _____ ______    ________   _______    ________      
|\  \     |\  \ |\   __  \ |\  \  |\___   ___\|\   __  \ |\   _ \  _   \ |\   ____\ |\  ___ \  |\   ___  \    
\ \  \    \ \  \\ \  \|\  \\ \  \ \|___ \  \_|\ \  \|\  \\ \  \\\__\ \  \\ \  \___|_\ \   __/| \ \  \\ \  \   
 \ \  \  __\ \  \\ \   __  \\ \  \     \ \  \  \ \  \\\  \\ \  \\|__| \  \\ \_____  \\ \  \_|/__\ \  \\ \  \  
  \ \  \|\__\_\  \\ \  \ \  \\ \  \____ \ \  \  \ \  \\\  \\ \  \    \ \  \\|____|\  \\ \  \_|\ \\ \  \\ \  \ 
   \ \____________\\ \__\ \__\\ \_______\\ \__\  \ \_______\\ \__\    \ \__\ ____\_\  \\ \_______\\ \__\\ \__\
    \|____________| \|__|\|__| \|_______| \|__|   \|_______| \|__|     \|__||\_________\\|_______| \|__| \|__|
                                                                            \|_________|                              
  </pre>
</header>
```

I have two more media queries that adapt the layout to be more mobile friendly, and I just have the font-size for the header scale with the media queries like the one above.

Ideally, I'd like for the header grid container/box to constrain and force the ASCII  tag to scale with it, as the screen size shrinks, but I don't know if that's possible given how  tags work.

Thank you for taking the time to read through all of this!

Comment: Change `font-size` in `header pre` to vw units. `font-size: 1vw;` seems to work okay.

Comment: I can't believe the solution was that simple. Thank you! The shrinking was quite aggressive and got way too small when reaching mobile screen sizes, but I was able to get around that by using a max() function.

Comment: Maybe look into `vmin` and `vmax` units though, to keep it working on extreme landscapes.

Comment: You don't have to post the answer inside your question - you can wait for Waltomsen to post it or write the answer yourself so this question doesn't appear unanswered.

Comment: I wrote the answer myself, but can't accept it as the answer yet, so I'll have to wait with that. @PeterKrebs

Comment: Ah I see it now ok. Voted up, I like it. You can also post the whole solution not just a short paragraph. You can make a running snippet BTW with the `<>` button if you care.

Comment: Rewrote the answer to be much more detailed, and it includes a much better solution. Hope it's good! Thank you for the guidance, btw! @PeterKrebs

Comment: clamp() is also useful for limiting the minimum and maximum sizes. You can also use calc(). I've upvoted your answer. Well-written. Nicely done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the changes I made! All other code is the exactly the same as above.

###### First solution: Works fine but scaling is quite aggressive.

```css
header pre {
 font-size: 0.5vw;
}
```

###### Second solution lessens the scaling issue, but it's still not quite what I wanted.

```css
header pre {
 font-size: max(0.5vw, 0.25rem);
}
```

###### Third and most effective solution, provides gentle/uniform scaling that seems to work really well on very small screens, and very big screens, too! Added minmax and max functions to prevent it from shrinking too much.

```css
body {
 grid-template-rows: minmax(2.5rem, 12vmin) 1fr 5rem;
}
header pre {
 font-size: max(0.2rem, 1vmin);
}
```

Thank you, [Adam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12571484/adam) and [somethinghere](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2991619/somethinghere), for the help!